# PyDub : Can't Save file in a different directory properly

Tags: python-3.x, audio, wav, pydub, audio-converter

I have been using this code to convert 10 .wav files in .mp3

```
song_dir = 'Desktop/Song_test/*wav'
song = glob(song_dir) 
print(song)
for song in song:
    mp3_song = os.path.splitext(song)[0] + '.mp3' 
    sound = pydub.AudioSegment.from_mp3(song)
    sound.export('Desktop/Song_test/Converted/', mp3_song, '.mp3', format="mp3")
print("Conversion Done")
```

What I want to actually achieve is to pick the .wav file from Song_Test convert it in .mp3 file and save it in a subdirectory within Song_Test named Converter. The new file should have the same name (for this I was trying to use `os.path.splitext` when I was not trying to save the output in a different directory, this was working fine and the converted files had the same name as the earlier file.

Upon saving it in a new directory, When I run this code error pops up, *TypeError: export() got multiple values for argument 'format'*. Please guide me how I can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing the export like this -

```
sound.export('Desktop/Song_test/Converted/' + mp3_song, format="mp3")
```

1. Using the '+' adds 'mp3_song' to the location/name string.
2. Adding '.mp3' seems to be redundant, since it's included in 'mp3_song'.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me turned out to be that Pydub doesn't create directories for the files it exports. The solution was to create the directory immediately before the `export()` call.

```
Path(directory).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
filename = f"{directory}\\{index}.{EXPORT_FILE_TYPE}"
file_object = sound.export(filename, format=EXPORT_FILE_TYPE)
file_object.close()
self.tagger.write_tags(filename)
```

Interestingly, I found I had to `close()` the file object created by PyDub before I could do additional processing on the file (which in my case was manipulating the file's metadata tags)